# How do you make the box transparent in CSS

Tags: css

I am fairly new to CSS, and I am writing for a website, but got stuck on how to make the box transparent. This is my code so far:

```
#left_box {
margin-top:0px;
min-width:10%;
max-width:10%;
height:800px;
background:orange;
position:absolute;
z-index:1;
left:0%;
top:0%;
opacity:80%;
}
```

Comment: [opacity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity) accepts a value between 0 and 1

Answer (score 2):

Use `opacity:0.8;`

```
#left_box {
margin-top:0px;
min-width:10%;
max-width:10%;
height:800px;
background:orange;
position:absolute;
z-index:1;
left:0%;
top:0%;
opacity:0.8;
filter: alpha(opacity=80);  /* IE8 and lower */
}
```

***Note:*** Opacity value is a number in the range 0.0 to 1.0, both included, representing the opacity of the channel, that is the value of its alpha channel. Any value outside the interval, though valid, is clamped to the nearest limit in the range.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity

Answer (score 0):

Try this, `opacity` is a **number** in the range 0.0 to 1.0.

```
#left_box {
....
opacity: 0.8;
filter: alpha(opacity=80); /* IE8 and lower */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just make the background of the box transparent and not the contents, you could use...

`background: rgba(255,255,255,.8);`.

However this isn't supported in older browsers.

You can read more about it here... http://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/